# UILongPressGestureRecognizer not working in with tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, scroll, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to use "UILongPressGestureRecognizer" but is not working:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        linhaVideo *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VideosCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell setCellHeight:cell.frame.size.height];
cell.containingTableView = tableView;

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                               initWithTarget:self 
                                               action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];


    cell.leftUtilityButtons = [self leftButtons];
    cell.delegate = self;

    return cell;
}

- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test"
                                                      message:@"test"
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this code?!? Nothing happen when I press for almost 3 seconds the cell.

tks

Comment: initially allocate your linhaVideo cell... create like this  linhaVideo *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VideosCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[linhaVideo alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"VideosCell"];
    }

Comment: Does your controller follow `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol?

Answer (score -1):

Common mistake, you forgot to set the delegate:

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                               initWithTarget:self 
                                               action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];

    longPress.delegate = self;//or something else you want
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Comment: The delegate isn't required to trigger the event. It's used to fine tune the recognizer, but in this case they just want it to fire.

Answer (score -2):

You should add the gesture on cell after she exists, not after you dequeue the cell in this moment cell doesn't exist, after you scroll dequeue has effect and give's you the proper cell otherwise you will get nil.

Comment: This is not correct, after you dequeue the cell it exists and will not return nil, you can try this just add a breakpoint and check. That is why after the dequeue you can add title, images… you can not do this with a view that points to nil.

Comment: Roberto I put a breakpoint after dequeue and i get nil only after i scroll the table i get the cell. I tried that with a table with 3 cells with 44.0f cell height.